# How to list all available maven lifecycles?

Tags: maven

In maven it is possible to list all the phases of some lifecycle with `help:describe`:

```
$ mvn help:describe -Dcmd=package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:2.2:describe (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] 'package' is a phase corresponding to this plugin:

It is a part of the lifecycle for the POM packaging 'pom'. This lifecycle includes the following phases:
* validate: Not defined
* initialize: Not defined
* generate-sources: Not defined
* process-sources: Not defined
* generate-resources: Not defined
* process-resources: Not defined
* compile: Not defined
* process-classes: Not defined
* generate-test-sources: Not defined
* process-test-sources: Not defined
* generate-test-resources: Not defined
* process-test-resources: Not defined
* test-compile: Not defined
* process-test-classes: Not defined
* test: Not defined
* prepare-package: Not defined
* package: Not defined
* pre-integration-test: Not defined
* integration-test: Not defined
* post-integration-test: Not defined
* verify: Not defined
* install: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install
* deploy: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy
```

This requires to specify some (arbitrary?) phase of that lifecycle.

I am aware of the [clean, default, and site lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

If I understood [this section](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugins-lifecycle.html) correctly it is also possible to add completely new lifecycles.

Is there a command to list all available lifecyles and which phases they consist of?

Comment: This is a very good queston.
Apart from the caveat in `help:describe` requiring `-Dcmd=...` that you have already mentioned there is another issue; It is also misleading when specifying `mvn help:describe -Dcmd=site-deploy` it says `'site-deploy' is a lifecycle with the following phases:` which is not true. It must be `'site-deploy' is in a lifecycle named 'site' with the following phases:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding.

By "custom lifecyle" the cited book mean custom bindings of goals to existing lifecylcle phases. The term Lifecycle is used for both, the lifecycle structure of the three maven lifecycles, consisting only of their emtpy phases as well as the lifecycle of a specific maven project/module.

So, you can only add lifecycles of the latter type, either as custom lifecycles for forking or as new bindings for a new packaging type. You cannot, however create a new lifecycle structure with completly new Lifecycle phases.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. @blackbuild: If you think the book is wrong/misleading, please provide a a PR to https://github.com/sonatype/maven-reference-en and see if the PR is accepted.

Comment: @Jarl: I don't actually think the book is wrong or misleading - or rather I don't know how it could be written more cleary. Still, I think the OP did misunderstand it (of course I might also have misunderstood the question). Where do you think the answer is wrong?

Comment: I don't think OP misunderstood anything, I understand the book much the same way as OP is refering to it. I think your interpretation of the explanation in the book is incorrect.
Your answers starts out by claiming "This is a misunderstanding". I don't think that OP has misunderstood anything. I think OP has asked a completely valid question: _How to list all available maven lifecycles?_

Comment: The OP question is obviously valid. It is a question of basic enumeration of what actionable arguments are there, so that it can be tuned to whatever purpose it fits.